# laravel checking pivot returns error contains() on a non-object

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

**Background:** 
What I am doing is I have made a page displaying a table with checkboxes for attendees and events. It was working until I tried to check my checkboxes based on a query through a pivot table through a belongs to many relation.

I have looked at some other threads and tried the same approach to check a pivot for existing entry data. I am using the contains() function to see if my attendee and scheduled_program_segment are matched, but for some reason my code gets this error.

**Problem:**

I get the error `Call to member function contains() on a non-object`.

Here is the bit of my code I think is relevent

```
   @foreach( Auth::user()->attendee as $attendee )
                    <td class="col-lg-1">
                    {{
                        Form::checkbox(
                            ($program->name . $attendee->first_name),
                            '1',
                            $attendee->scheduled_program_segments->contains($attendee->id)
                        )
                    }}
```

I tried changing to $attendee as well. Same error.
Also, when I run

```
  {{$attendee->scheduled_program_segments()->get()}}
```

I get the following which I am assuming means I have the pivot table and model set up correctly, but it's not working so maybe I am wrong here.

`[{"id":"1","created_at":"2014-11-14 15:19:44","updated_at":"2014-11-14 15:19:44","name":"Minecraft","description":"","date":"2014-11-06","cost":"20.00","start_time":"16:30:00","end_time":"17:30:00","location":"Cookstown","scheduled_program_id":"1","program_segment_id":"1","pivot":{"attendee_id":"1","scheduled_program_segment_id":"1"}},{"id":"1","created_at":"2014-11-14 15:19:44","updated_at":"2014-11-14 15:19:44","name":"Minecraft","description":"","date":"2014-11-06","cost":"20.00","start_time":"16:30:00","end_time":"17:30:00","location":"Cookstown","scheduled_program_id":"1","program_segment_id":"1","pivot":{"attendee_id":"1","scheduled_program_segment_id":"1"}}]`

Comment: Could you please update your question with your model(s)? Especially the Attendee class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$attendee->scheduled_program_segments
```

is a m-m relation, so obviously it returns `null`, because Laravel 4+ relations **need** to be `camelCased` in order to work as [dynamic properties](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#dynamic-properties) (that is what you're trying to do).

So you can either rename your relation to `scheduledProgramSegments()` and then call it:

```
$attendee->scheduledProgramSegments
// or
$attendee->scheduled_program_segments // yes, this will work as well
```

or change that line as follows (which I'd rather not suggest):

```
$attendee->scheduled_program_segments()->get()->contains(...)
```

Comment: So I started changing all my model relation functions to camelCase, then I realized that my database uses snake_case. Correct me if I'm wrong but this is standard for most databases. This complicates things because I don't want to think about which case when accessing model data...either all camel or all snake...but not a mix!   
(field data would be accessed like `name->first_name` because `first_name` is the field in the database...but program_segment would be `name->ProgramSegment`, very confusing :S

Comment: Like said above - `snake_cased` relations will work as well (as dynamic properties).

Comment: yes, I decided to use ->get()->contains so I can leave everything snake_case even though it is not suggested.

Comment: I think you didn't get my point - when you define relation as `camelCased` you **can** call it `snake_cased`, like this: `$attendee->scheduled_program_segments`.

Comment: trying now to store this pivot `attendee->scheduled_program_segments->attach($program_id)` seems like it only works with the camelCaseName `attendee->scheduledProgramSegments()->attach($program_id)` which is really god dam confusing.

Comment: Well, first off you need `()` there. And yes, you need to refer the method name, which is `camelCase`, but to be honest - just be consistent about naming, period.

Comment: Sorry, it's confusing to explain, I wanted to be consistent with SQL database field/table naming conventions...so ORM for field names `model->field_name` is the same as ORM for relations `model->relation_table->field_name`. But in short this is impossible because Laravel requires camelCased for magic and `->get()` but `->attach()` doesn't change the camelCased back to snake_cased...which will cause some confusing for people if they are using snake_cased and pivots. I think lots of people would encounter this snafu. I appreciate your guidance. Would have never gotten this far without you.

Comment: Everything is working. I just feel slightly dirty that I have snake_cased and camelCased mapping mixed around now. I will probably go back and rename everything again to be all snake_cased and just deal with having `->get()` inside the `function->call->chain`.

Comment: If that suits you, do it. Just a hint: you don't need **dynamic properties** at all, if you always eager load (or lazy load using `load()` method) those relationships. Then `snake_cased` relations will works as well.